# Javascript: Video pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to write a javascript function that operates as follows:

Input: Youtube Video ID (i.e. F3v39wnv), height, width and name

Action: Popup a new window w/ the specified name width and height, showing the specified video.

I have figured out a rudimentary way to do it (by using document.write() ) but I understand that this opens the page up to vulnerabilities.

I am a strong programmer, I'm just not at all familiar with javascript.  What is the standard method for passing arguments to a new webpage?  I have been able to have the source page generate the new window with all of the specified arguments as follows:  videoplayer.htm?vid=(VidID)?height=(height)?width=(width)?name=(name), but I haven't been able to read those arguments from videoplayer.htm

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know how videoplayer.htm can retrieve its parameters?

Comment: Right, as well as how to use that information to generate the actual webpage.  Right now I'm using document.write, but I understand that that method is subject to injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window.location. More specifically, window.location.pathname will return everything behind the hostname. In this page, that would be "questions/4856801/javascript-video-pop-up-window"

Then you can use the String.split method to split the url into its arguments

```
var arguments = window.location.pathname.split("?")[1].split("&");
```

Should split "videoplayer.htm?vid=3&height=4&width=5" into ["vid=3", "height=4", "width=5"]

Then further splitting each argument by the "=" character should give you a tag => value array
"vid=3".split("=") becomes ["vid", "3"]

---

```
function fetchArguments() {
    var arg = window.location.pathname.split("?")[1].split("&"), // arguments
        len = arr.length, // length of arguments
        obj = {}, // object that maps argument id to argument value
        i, // iterator
        arr; // array

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr = arg[i].split("="); // split our first argument
        obj[arr[0]] = arr[1]; // e.g. obj["vid"] = "3"
    }

    return obj;
}

function loadVideo() {
    var args = fetchArguments(),
        iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

    iframe.title = "YouTube video player";
    iframe.width = args["width"];
    iframe.height = args["height"];
    iframe.src = "youtube.com/embed/" + args["vid"];
    iframe.type = "text/html";
    iframe.className = "youtube-player";
    // I'm sure you get the idea

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(iframe); // we append the iframe to the document's body
}
```

So I'm not sure what exactly you want to do with the iframe, but in my example the loadVideo() function will create an  element and attach it to the document's body

Comment: Thanks Bart, that's a perfect answer for half my question.  Could you also help me out with the safe way to now use that information in the videoplayer page?  I would like to have the title be "name" and replace the appropriate values in this string:

<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="!!!_WIDTH_!!!" height="!!_HEIGHT_!!" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/!!VID_ID!!!" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>

Comment: Edited my post. Didn't test it so I hope it doesn't have any syntax errors. Is that more or less what you need?

Comment: Yup, I had to do a little editing, but this worked perfectly, and helped me understand Javascript's syntax much better.  Thanks.